# Comparing elements of one dictionary to ranges of values in another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value, key-value-coding

```
valid = {'Temp': [10, 55], 'rain_percent': [49, 100], 'humidity': [30,50]}
data = {'Temp': 30.45, 'rain_percent': 80.56 }

min_temp , max_temp = valid['Temp']
if not(min_temp <= data['Temp'] <= max_temp):
    print "Bad Temp"

min_rain , max_rain = valid['rain_percent']
if not(min_rain <= data['rain_percent'] <= max_rain):
    print "It's not going to rain"
```

This is what I'm doing with the 2 dictionarties I'm having. I know that this check can be further modified. Since both the dictionaries i.e `valid` and `data` have the same `keys`, there must be some better way of implementing this check. Can anyone help me in this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I edited the title to clarify the problem I think you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to check if each value `data[k]` is in the range defined by the 2-element list/tuple `valid[k]`.

Try using a `for` loop and [`dict.items()`](//docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to iterate through `data` and compare each value to the corresponding range in `valid`:

```
valid = {'Temp': [10, 55], 'rain_percent': [49, 100], 'humidity': [30,50]}
data = {'Temp': 30.45, 'rain_percent': 80.56, 'humidity': 70 }

for key,val in data.items():
    min, max = valid[key]
    if not( min <= val <= max ):
       print "%s=%g is out of valid range (%g-%g)" % (key, val, min, max)
    else:
       print "%s=%g is in the valid range (%g-%g)" % (key, val, min, max)
```

In the case of the example `data` values I gave, it will print this:

```
rain_percent=80.56 is in the valid range (49-100)
Temp=30.45 is in the valid range (10-55)
humidity=70 is out of valid range (30-50)
```

Comment: I would have a try-except around `min, max = valid[key]`and the if-else statements.

Comment: Arnab Datta, **why**? If you're getting the contents of `valid` from a possibly-erroneous source, then you should probably scrub them before going into this loop. If certain keys in `data` are not present in `valid`, then the correct behavior is not obvious from the OP's question, but one of the simpler possibilities is to use `valid.get(key, (defaultmin,defaultmax))` instead of `valid[key]`.

Comment: Thanks @DanLenski Thanks for the help.
The other way to tackle the next issue of If certain keys in data are not present in valid : - 
`if key in valid.keys():
    min, max = valid[key]
    if not( min <= val <= max ):
       print "%s=%g is out of valid range (%g-%g)" % (key, val, min, max)
    else:
       print "%s=%g is in the valid range (%g-%g)" % (key, val, min, max)`

Thanks again. :)

Comment: Sure, there are many ways to handle missing keys, depending entirely on the semantics of how you want to handle this case. (BTW, you shouldn't post long Python snippets in comments since they get concatenated into a one-line mess as you can see :-P)

Answer (score 1):

This answer builds off @Dan's.

It could be the case that you want to add other parameters to your 'valid' dictionary such as avg, standard deviation, etc and many more data points such as air_pressure, wind_speed, visibility, etc.

Especially in the case where you have **many more data points**(temp, humidity, etc.) and **many more parameters and labels** (min, max, 'high temp,' 'low temp,' etc.), you would want your 'valid' dictionary to be more descriptive.  You can then write general functions that are more flexible and descriptive depending on the depth of your 'valid' dictionary.

Here's an example.  Let's now call the 'valid' dictionary 'parameters.'

```
parameters = {
    'temp': {
        'min':10, 
        'max':55,
        'avg':40,
        'stddev':10, 
        'in_range_label':"Good Temp", 
        'out_range_label':"Bad Temp", 
        'above_average_label':"Above average temp", 
        'below_average_label':"Below average temp",
    },
    'rain_percent': {
        'min':49, 
        'max':100,
        'avg':75, 
        'in_range_label':"Going to rain", 
        'out_range_label':"Not going to rain", 
        'above_average_label':"Above average rain", 
        'below_average_label':"Below average rain", 
        }, 
    'humidity': {
        'min':30, 
        'max':50,
        'avg':45, 
        'in_range_label':"Humid", 
        'out_range_label':"Not humid" , 
        'above_average_label':"Above average hemp", 
        'below_average_label':"Below average humidity",
        }
    }

data = {'temp': 30.45, 'rain_percent': 80.56 }

def check_min_max(data, parameters):
    for k, v in data.items():
        min = parameters[k]['min']
        max = parameters[k]['max']
        if min <= v <= max:
            print '{}={}, {}'.format(k, v, parameters[k]['in_range_label'])
        else:
            print '{}={}, {}'.format(k, v, parameters[k]['out_range_label'])

def check_avg(data, parameters):
    for k, v in data.items():
        avg = parameters[k]['avg']
        if v > avg:
            print '{}={}, {}'.format(k, v, parameters[k]['above_average_label'])
        else:
            print '{}={}, {}'.format(k, v, parameters[k]['below_average_label'])

check_min_max(data, parameters)
check_avg(data, parameters)

>>>
rain_percent=80.56, Going to rain
temp=30.45, Good Temp
rain_percent=80.56, Above average rain
temp=30.45, Below average temp
```